# AWS Cloud formations: Configure Elastic Beanstalk with ApplicationVersionLifecycleConfig

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've an EB: I use the aws cli to deploy apps to my EB.
First I upload to S3
Then I create a new version (or update an existing one)
I update the environment.

This works quite well, but now I have a lot of versions already. Since my environment is created with cloud formations I want to adapt it.

I read about the following setting for Elastic beanstalk [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticbeanstalk-application-maxcountrule.html).

```
DeleteSourceFromS3: Boolean
Enabled: Boolean
MaxCount: Integer
```

This is something I could use. After a MaxCount of versions EB will throw away the old version (also from s3 if I want too).

Is there a way to recreate this with an `AWS CLI` command or parameter?

If not, I will need to integrate it in my cloudformations. (AWS CLI can handle it scripted, but just making the setting in my console is not allowed).

The problem is the integration in my cloudformation.
How can I add this to my EB which just looks like this now:

```
Type: "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application"
Properties:
  ApplicationName: xxx
  Description: xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloudformation snippet for EB with Resource Lifecycle settings:

```
Type: "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application"
Properties:
  ApplicationName: String
  Description: String
  ResourceLifecycleConfig:
    ServiceRole: string
    VersionLifecycleConfig:
      MaxCountRule:
        Enabled: true
        MaxCount: 5
        DeleteSourceFromS3: true
      MaxAgeRule:
        Enabled: true
        MaxAgeInDays: 10
        DeleteSourceFromS3: true
```

Comment: Do you have an example service role with enough permissions to perform this action? I've been getting `Insufficient privileges for IAM PassRole Action` when passing my role ARN for the environment which uses the managed policy `AWSElasticBeanstalkService` and is allowed to assume the role for the Elastic Beanstalk service.